# Scala filter substring from string

Tags: scala, filter

i'm trying to filter a substring from a string. The problem is instead of just removing the sub string "fd" from "fdskufh". It removes "fd" from the string, but then also removes the second f, so the new string is "skuh". Any suggestions would be much appreciated? I have been using the function below:

```
        def stripChars(s:String, ch:String)= s filterNot (ch contains _)
```

Comment: `s.replace(ch, "")` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at what your line of code means: it's going to iterate over all the characters in `s`, and it's going to filter out any characters that are in `ch`. So what you observe is indeed what is to be expected.

You can use a regular expression:

```
val regex = "fd".r
val input = "fdskufh"

val result = regex.replaceAllIn(input, "")
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Will put this as the correct answer as soon as i'm able to. Thanks!!!

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but the obvious problem is that it won't work if the string to be removed contains special characters for regular expressions.

Comment: I downvoted it for a different reason: I didn't think the question is complex enough for a regex solution. There are existing Java/Scala functions perfect for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
scala> def stripChars(s: String, ch: String) = s.split(ch).mkString
stripChars: (s: String, ch: String)String

scala> stripChars("fdskufh", "fd")
res194: String = skufh
```

This has the advantage of returning the original string if the character sequence does not exists. So you can have this:

```
scala> stripChars("fdskufh", "ff")
res195: String = fdskufh
```

And it would work for the following as well:

```
scala> stripChars("fdskufhfdsh", "fd")
res196: String = skufhsh
```

EDIT:

Or you can ignore all that and just go with `s.replace(ch, "")` like Sergey suggested